# Running integrated mode and classic mode on same iis7 server

Tags: iis-7, hosting

Is it possible? And if yes; how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. In IIS7, you just have to create multiple App Pools for each type of application. On my dev machine, I have IIS7 running with App Pools for the following:

.NET 1.1 in Classic Mode
.NET 2.0 in Classic Mode
.NET 3.5 in Integrated Mode

Those seem to take care of any application I've ran in to so far. If you've got others, whip up another App Pool and assign your applications accordingly.